# Java method appends method

Tags: java, oop

I have seen in some codes OOP construction like that:

```
Obj o=new Obj();
o.setVisibility(true).setHeight(100).setWidth(100).color(Color.Black);
```

I want to make similar object, i.e I want to call some method after another, if you now what I mean. 
I have tried to find this on internet and OOP books, but I didn't know exactly what to search.

Thanks.

Comment: This should be a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java_Example